# Wait for next block when testing with TestRPC

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-debugging

I'm running some tests over my contract using TestRPC and Mocha.

I'm writing a debt manager. My data structure has a field called `validity`, which is semantically a date that determines until when this debt can be paid without a fine.

Some of my business rules are:

1. I cannot insert a registry with `validity` in the past
2. When I try to pay the debt and it is past its `validity`, I have to add a fine to the due value.

My contract has a rule that checks (simplified version):

```
function getValue() returns (uint) {
    if (now > validity) 
        return value + fine;
    else
        return value;
}
```

I generate a registry with `validity` very near in the future in order to allow it to be inserted.

I tried to set a delay for the test case, in order to get the "out of validity" condition when I want to `getValue()` of the registry, but I'm not getting into that branch. It keeps returning only `value` instead of `value + fine`.

Then I discovered that [`now` is just an alias to `block.timestamp`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Features#now-variable), which leads me to a problem:

How can I delay execution of the test until the next block is mined?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function `evm_increaseTime` to artificially increase the time during the tests with testrpc.

> `evm_increaseTime` : Jump forward in time. Takes one parameter, which is
>   the amount of time to increase in seconds. Returns the total time
>   adjustment, in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you use something like this ?

```
modifier onlyAfter(uint _time) { if (now <= _time) throw; _ }

function getValue() onlyAfter(validity) returns (uint){
```

Comment: Yes, I could, but this is not what my problem is. I'm running test cases and need to wait for the next block.